# Start Jar in Linux "javafx/application/Application"

Tags: linux, java

System Information is:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

 Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

Linux Version is:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.19.0-kali3-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc version 8.2.0 (Debian 8.2.0-16)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.20-1kali1 (2019-02-14)
```

Java Version:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The error when trying to execute the .jar:

```
java -jar any_game.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 13 more
```

I've tried to change the Java version in dpkg --config, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of workaround this is:

- Install `openjfx` package
- Run `jar` as:

```
java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web -jar jarFile.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You must install `openjfx`package for support of JavaFX applications
Also you will need to install libraries like `libopenjfx-java`, `libopenjfx-jni`.
Maybe you will need to add the path to CLASSPATH

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/openjfx/lib/
```

Comment: sudo apt policy openjfx
openjfx:
  Installed: 11.0.2+1-1
  Candidate: 11.0.2+1-1
  Version table:
 *** 11.0.2+1-1 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: It is already installed but doesn't work for some reason and I dont know why...

Comment: @JaBush, check where are located classes of JavaFX and add the dir in CLASS_PATH vairable

Comment: How do I check that? @Romeo Ninov

Comment: @JaBush, you can check which files contain package with command `dpkg-query -L <package_name>`

Comment: And how do I add them to CLASS_PATH?

Comment: The .jar i want to execute is something I downloaded

Comment: @JaBush, did you read my edited answer?

Comment: I didn't notice you updated it, I'll try it asap and reply-back then or just mark the answer as solved, depending on the outcome

Comment: Did you mean `CLASSPATH` without the underscore? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218288/java-environment-variables-classpath-vs-class-path/8218388

Comment: Right, @BenjaminPeter, will correct my answer

Comment: Where do I paste your classpath line ("export ...") in Eclipse? I tried following this: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse and I got as far as getting the same error as you. It doesn't go in the Run configuration arguments does it?

Comment: I am struggling to understand the "maybe" part of your answer, and I don't know if that's the cause of my problem. Does the "export ..." effectively do the same as the step described under the header  "Environment variable" in the article I linked above?

Comment: @pateksan, it is the same, I provide the end command you need to execute (and add to `.bashrc` or/and `.bash_profile`)