# Add openjfx class path in debian for Java11

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, java

Distribution is Kali Linux
Java11 is installed:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Openjfx is also installed:

```
apt policy openjfx
openjfx:
  Installed: 11.0.2+1-1
  Candidate: 11.0.2+1-1
  Version table:
 *** 11.0.2+1-1 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

However, when I want to start something using Java11 that requires OpenJFX it wont work.

Also, how do I install OpenJFX for Java8? With

```
sudo apt install openjfx
```

I only get openjfx for Java11

When I want to start something using Java that includes openjfx:

```
java -jar file.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/505130/117549?

Comment: More likely a following question as I didn't know what the issue was. Now I'm aware it's openjfx not being found by java11 and I'm not sure how to include it.

Comment: I mention it because it seemed like Romeo had a solution that you were going to test and reply back with. The bulk of the question seems (to me) identical.

Comment: I didn't figure out how to add the path though and still am stuck with the same Problem...

Comment: @JaBush, this is not a reason to ask new question. Just add comment in the first question